# Complex Infinite Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

What does $\sum_{n=k}^\infty {n\choose k}a^{n-k}$ converge to for any $k\geq 0$ and any $|a|<1$?

I'm working on a small paper where in part of it I find analytic continuations for functions defined as power series by re-centering the power series at a different point inside the radius of convergence and hoping that this re-centering will give me a larger radius of convergence and thus a larger area in which the function is analytic. I'm working through a concrete example I've made up in similar motivation to the "Worked Example" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) and I have reduced the new coefficients of my re-centered power series to the infinite sum above ($k$ being the index of the coefficient in the power series).

I've attempted to alter the sum such as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {n+k\choose n}a^n$ and a few other ones using combinatoric identities. I've also attempted to see how I can relate this to the binomial theorem because there is definitely some resemblance to the expansion for $(1+a)^n$, but I cannot get it to match well enough to conclude anything. When $k=0$ I get a very nice geometric series but when $k>0$ I have run out of ideas of how to find what it converges to. I don't know of any formulas for finding what a series converges when it is not geometric so if anyone knows of any this would be great. Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Edit: In my example I started with the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$ which clearly is the Taylor Series expansion for $(1-z)^{-1}$, but I am trying to pretend that I do not know the original function so that my re-centering of the series can be used for general power series where an explicit function is not known. So then in my example I re-centered around $a$ to get $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k(z-a)^k$ and I used the Cauchy Integral Formula and Residue Theorem to find that $c_k=\sum_{n=k}^\infty {n\choose k} a^{n-k}$.

Comment: sir try (1+a)^n expansion

Comment: @ILoveMath perhaps I've made a mistake but $(1+a)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j}$ which is different from my series mainly because in mine we have ${n\choose k}$ where $k$ is constant and $n$ varies but in the binomial expansion $n$ is constant and $j$ changes.

Comment: You could perhaps change the title to indiacate that the question is not about convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with
$$
(1-a)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = (\text{polynomial in $a$ of degree }k-1) + \sum_{n=k}^\infty a^n
$$
and differentiating $k$ times, we obtain
$$
k! (1-a)^{-k-1} = 0 + \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} a^{n-k},
$$
which shows that the series in the OP is exactly $(1-a)^{-k-1}$.

Comment: This is certainly correct, but I forgot to provide some context in my question which I have updated in my edit. Thank you.

Comment: I concede that my answer isn't as helpful if one doesn't have an idea what shape the answer should have. Consequently, I recommend that we teach ourselves the semi-isolated rule of thumb that infinite sums with simple binomial coefficients like this tend to equal simple binomial expressions.